# Solving a differential equations and finding the maximum amplitude

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a practice exercise from my differential equation class:

Let $y'' + py' + qy = cos (wt)$ where $p,q,w$ are all positive and let $Acos(wt+\alpha)$ denote the particular solution. Find the value of $w$ so that A attains the maximum value.

It did not take too long to find that $ \displaystyle A = \frac {1} {\sqrt {(q-w^2)^2+(pw)^2}} $.

So I thought I can just find the *minimum* value of $g(w) = (q-w^2)^2+(pw)^2$ because $g(w)$ is always positive.

$g'(w) $

$= 2(q-w^2)*(-2w)+2p^2w$

$=2w(p^2-2(q-w^2))$

$=2w(2w^2+(p^2-2q))$

It is easy to see that $\displaystyle lim_{w \to \infty} g'(w)=\infty$, so there are two possibilities. 1) $g'(w)>0$ for all $w>0$. 2) There exists $w_0 >0$ such that $g'(w_0)=0$.

In the second case it is possible to decide the value of $w$ but if $p^2-2q>0$ then $g'(w)$ will not have *minimum* value. However the problem does not seem to provide any constraint about $p,q,r$.

What is wrong with my argument? Could you help me figure out how to find the solution?

p.s.

It seems that the A attains the maximum value when $w=0$, but the problem states that $w$ must be positive. If this were exam, how should I answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p^2-2q \gt 0$ corresponds to an overdamped oscillator.  It will have maximum forced amplitude at $w=0$ as your analysis shows.  Intuitively, the resistance will cause it to lag behind the driving function, and the slower the driving function, the closer it comes to matching the amplitude of the driving function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, I can disregard the possibility that $p^2-2q>0$ because it is considered to be overdamped?

Comment: @Tengu:  I don't think you should ignore it, but the maximum amplitude will come at $w=0$ with $A=\frac 1q$.  This corresponds to the forcing function being a fixed force in one direction. The system will take a fixed offset in the direction of the force.   The offset will be the force divided by the spring constant.  At any frequency above zero, the amplitude of the oscillation will be less than this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Hmm if it were an exam, how should I answer? the problem says $w$ is positive so...

Comment: @Tengu:  I don't see $w$ is positive, just $p,q,r$  If you are given $w \gt 0$ the amplitude will have no maximum, as cutting the frequency in half will always increase the amplitude.

Comment: I'm sorry. $p,q,r$ are my typos. My handout says $p,q,w$. Judging from what you explained for me, it seems that it was my professor's typo.